# CSRF токен в одностраничном проекте

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel, spa

В проекте (Laravel + Angular JS) frontend и backend работают независимо, т.е. Laravel лишь играет роль некого Rest API. Генерация отображений полностью лежит на Angular JS. Как пользоваться CSRF токеном в таком проекте? Есть идея получать его get методом из API, возможно, я ошибаюсь: не представляю, как это отразится на безопасности; в этом случае - как правильно? Возможно, проверку CSRF стоит вообще отключить? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше отказаться от идеи хранения каких бы то ни было данных в сессии или в куках вовсе. Тем более, что REST API рекомендуется делать не имеющим состояния (stateless). Такой API не будет нуждаться в защите CSRF-токеном вовсе.

Вместо этого следует использовать токены безопасности. Такой токен выдается в ответ на запрос входа в систему, хранится на стороне js - и в дальнейшем передается слою API на каждый запрос.

Comment: Но и в том и другом случае токен должен храниться на стороне сервера, чтобы его было возможно сравнить с тем, что приходит от клиента. В таком случае не понимаю, как это можно сделать без сессий?

Comment: @АндрейТаланин либо храните его в базе - либо используйте цифровую подпись

Answer (score 3):

Один из вариантов изменить файл app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
//добавить в Routes список url какие CSRF не будет проверять
private $openRoutes = ['feedback', 'main/first', 'main/second'];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { 
    foreach($this->openRoutes as $route) {

      if ($request->is($route)) {
        return $next($request);
      }
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }
```

Comment: Начиная с 5.1 можно добавить исключения в свойство ``$except``. Всё остальное Laravel сделает сам. [Laravel::Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris).

Comment: Спасибо, но значит ли это, что вы согласны, что в этом случае, токен следует получать get запросом?